# solr DIH: field composed by other fields

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

Here my sql query:

```
select id, 'AAA' AS one, 'BBB' AS two from tableX
```

DIH config:

```
<entity
    name="item"
    query="select id, 'AAA' AS one, 'BBB' AS two from tableX"
    transformer="TemplateTransformer, RegexTransformer">

        <field column="nt1_id" name="id"/>
        <field column="one" name="oneone_s" regex="\w" replaceWith="C"/>
        <field column="two" name="twotwo_s" regex="\w" replaceWith="D"/>
        <field column="three" name="three_s" template="${item.oneone_s}-${item.twotwo_s}"/>
```

So, `three_s` is composed by `oneone_s` field and `twotwo_s`.

However, when I query documents:

```
{
    "id":"244027",
    "oneone_s":"CCC",
    "twotwo_s":"DDD",
    "_version_":1682634241556348928},
  {
    "id":"244029",
    "oneone_s":"CCC",
    "twotwo_s":"DDD",
    "_version_":1682634241558446080},
  {
    "id":"244031",
    "oneone_s":"CCC",
    "twotwo_s":"DDD",
    "_version_":1682634241558446081},
  {
     ...
```

**EDIT**:

I've tried setting a fixed value on `three_s` field:

```
<field column="three" name="three_s" template="fixed-value"/>
```

`three_s` value is created:

```
{
    "id":"244482",
    "oneone_s":"CCC",
    "twotwo_s":"DDD",
    "three_s":"fixed-value",
    "_version_":1682896666575765504},
{
   ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing you at least have to wrap your inner field inside a separate entity to get access to the outer variables. I'm guessing that you only have access to the row values and not the field named values. You could do the regex handling in SQL instead to work around that.

Comment: Which query shoukd I set into nested entity?

Comment: I'm not sure if it'd help, but you could try wrapping the part that relies on the outer values in a separate entity; but my guess is that the template vars will refer to whatever was retrieved and not your transformed values.

Comment: I just realized that you should at least get a `-` in your field .. is the `CCC` field defined in your schema?

Comment: `CCC` is the replaced value. Did you mean `three_s`? It's a synamic field...

Comment: Yes, I meant `three_s`. If it's defined as a dynamic field then it should at least give something, yes; have you tried just having a static value there instead? From the older wiki documentation: "If a template string contains placeholders or variables they must be defined when the transformer is being evaluated. _An undefined variable causes the entire template instruction to be ignored._" - so that explains why there isn't any content there.

Comment: I've edited post. Shortly, `three_s` field is created with `fixed-value`... What do yu suggest me...?

Comment: Move your replacement to the SQL itself, so that the values returned available inside your entities has already been parsed; use an update chain or move away from using DIH for advanced processing.